# How to toggle mouse support in vim?

Tags: vim

I have been working on my laptop a lot lately, and I am accidentally clicking while typing.  I know I could remove `set mouse=a` in my `.vimrc`, but sometimes I like using the mouse.

What can I do to create a toggle function to toggle mouse support?

Comment: Why not use `mouse=nv`, so that it's not enabled during insert mode?

Comment: This might fit my use-case, but I was really looking for a function to toggle it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of an option by using its name with a `&` prepended. So a simple toggle function for the `mouse` option would be:

```
function! ToggleMouse()
    " check if mouse is enabled
    if &mouse == 'a'
        " disable mouse
        set mouse=
    else
        " enable mouse everywhere
        set mouse=a
    endif
endfunc
```

This toggles between "no mouse" and "mouse in all modes". You can use it via `:call ToggleMouse()`

PS: don't use something like this for options that are boolean, for these `:set option!` can be used to invert them.

Answer (score 10):

Add below code in `.vimrc` file.

```
  map <F3> <ESC>:exec &mouse!=""? "set mouse=" : "set mouse=nv"<CR>
```